# Getting strings from user and returning an array of pointers for them, all runtime

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I'm using a function called `get_string()` which returns a pointer to a string to get input from the keyboard. At the end of the program `char **arr` should hold an array of pointers to the strings entered using the keyboard. `char *tmp_arr_ptr` is used as a temporary pointer for a case memory allocation fails (not to lose all the data).

At 1st I allocate 1 char sized space for arr. After that in the for loop, `tmp_str_ptr` gets a pointer to a string from the function. If this string has no characters in it the loop is broken out from. If the string is not empty, the current one before last cell gets an address for `tmp_str_ptr`. The process is repeated until an empty string is entered and then a NULL in inserted at the last space in arr (this is in order to pass arr as a pointer without the number of elements in it so the function will know when to stop looking for additional pointers).

The code works fine for up to two strings, more than that and I start getting errors. Also I get a warning on `arr=tmp_arr_ptr;` saying assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] and would like to resolve that as well.

This is the latest updated version of my code with fixed that reflects comments from users around here:

```
char **arr;
char **tmp_arr_ptr;
char *tmp_str_ptr;
int   i;

int main()
{
    if((arr=malloc(sizeof(*arr)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory, Exiting.\n");
        printf("malloc for arr");
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter string\n");
        printf("-->");
        tmp_str_ptr=get_string();
        if(*tmp_str_ptr=='\n')
            break;
        tmp_arr_ptr=realloc(arr,(i+2)*sizeof(**arr));
        if(tmp_arr_ptr!=NULL)
        {
            arr=tmp_arr_ptr;
            arr[i]=tmp_str_ptr;
            arr[i+1]=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            free(arr);
            printf("Error allocating memory, Exiting.\n");
            printf("realloc for tmp_arr_ptr");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("The most common character among the strings is %c",char_with_most_appearances(arr));

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]!=NULL)
            free(arr[i]);
        else
        {
            free(arr);
            break;
        }
    }

    free(tmp_str_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

So after running the debugger it seems that the char_with_most_appearances causes a segmentation error.
Here is the function:

```
char char_with_most_appearances(char **str_arr_ptr)
{
    int i=0,j,most=0,loc=0;
    int count_array[128]={0};

    while((str_arr_ptr[i]!=NULL)
    {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(str_arr_ptr[i]);j++)
            count_array[(int)str_arr_ptr[i][j]]++;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        if(count_array[i]>most)
        {
            most=count_array[i];
            loc=i;
        }
    }

    return (char)loc;
}
```

At 1st, it checks that the pointer is not NULL (last element in pointer array), next it will go through the array and count how many times each character appears and save that info in an array called count_array. It has 128 cells like ASCII and the char ASCII value is used as an index for the array. For example is the character 'a' is found then count_array[97] gets +1. After all the string was scanned, the biggest element in the array is searched and it's location is returned with a cast to a char which actually returns it's ASCII char.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Cramer - http://s28.postimg.org/czicn12od/err.png

Comment: I would try running it in a debugger (looks like you're on windows, if you're in an IDE then there should be one built in). Learning to use a debugger is a necessary (and very helpful) skill. It will tell you which line is accessing the wrong bit of memory and you can work backwards to find where that address comes from.

Comment: @Cramer - Just did that and posted the code the causes the error. This line - for(j=0;j<strlen(str_arr_ptr[i]);j++)

Comment: That line isn't in the code above. Have a look around to see what might be going wrong, perhaps `i` is greater than the length of `str_arr_ptr`?

Comment: @Cramer - That's correct, it's in the function char_with_most_appearances which I added to my original post at the bottom.

Comment: @Cramer - i initialized to 0 at the beginning of the function, and the pointer is checked for being NULL, if it's not, a for loop scans the string from j=0 to j<strlen(str_arr_ptr[i]). after that i is promoted and the condition is checked again so I can't think of a situation where i could be out of bound since the condition won't be met as the last pointer is arr is NULL.

Comment: I've added an answer down the bottom, but you should go through your code and figure it out for yourself. Debugging is a crucial skill and not really for Stack Overflow.

Comment: _warning on arr=tmp_arr_ptr; saying assignment from incompatible pointer type_ `char *tmp_arr_ptr;` change to `char **tmp_arr_ptr;`

Comment: `free(tmp_arr_ptr);` no need.

Comment: `arr[i+1]=NULL;` --> `arr[i]=NULL;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Please see my original post for an updated code. I changed the tmp_arr_ptr to ** and now inserting the NULL pointer at what I believe is the last cell in the allocated space so it is an array of string pointers terminating with null. This time it runs OK but only up to 8 strings, after that it will return an error of not being able to allocate memory.

Comment: i don't know your updated code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - I just edited the realloc command (size) and now I'm manipulating the allocated memory space only when realloc doesn't return NULL (it's in my original post on the top of the page).

Comment: `free(arr);
    free(tmp_arr_ptr);` , you are trying to release a double.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - So I need to do it with a while loop and index? Thanks for that, however do you have any idea why the program only takes up to 8 strings before not being able to allocate more memory? I am out of ideas.

Comment: _program only takes up to 8 strings_, I can not feel any special reason. this code differ from the actual code probably.

Comment: I only changed the last section with the free command after your comment. I will edit and re-post the current version, although nothing really changed.

Comment: `while((str_arr_ptr[i]!=NULL)` can't compile.(so this is not actual code)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Compiles without any errors using GCC. The code now is copy + paste from my code.

Comment: Bullshit. There is no should be able to compile but have not seen several of the brackets. You must number of parentheses are the same. 
 e.g `while((..))` , but your code  `while((..)`.

Answer (score 0):

At first didn't notice your realloc. You need to first assign your tmp_arr_ptr to arr before you can write in the additional space:

```
tmp_arr_ptr=realloc(arr,(i+1)*sizeof(*arr));
if(tmp_arr_ptr!=NULL)
     arr=tmp_arr_ptr;
     arr[i]=tmp_str_ptr;
```

Comment: Until the loop is done running for the last time (got empty string) I can't tell the size of the required space. I thought I am reallocating space in the loop and adding pointers to arr ?

Comment: I just noticed that as well and changed the code (a second before seeing your answer) but it runs the same way. However this was an error, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocated for the final `NULL` pointer.

Comment: arr[i+1]=NULL, just after the for loop in main. I always allocate i+1 for the new memory so after leaving the for loop in main i can set the last cell to NULL.

Comment: @user34920 you never allocated space for it.

Comment: I've changed the code. Runs the same I'm afraid. I am able to get to the line that causes the problem but I did not manage to see the array of pointers in such a way that I'll be able to see if something is pointing wrong.

Comment: @user34920, we're not here to debug for you sorry but rather to answer specific questions. You now know much more than before, see if you can debug it yourself, or perhaps find a forum or IRC.